# non-linear scrolling

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom

Scrolling `s` is like, well, linear:

```
s(x) = x             with x among [0, ∞]
```

[image]

I'd like to apply [a more fancy function](http://jqueryui.com/demos/effect/easing.html), say `x^2`:

[image]

but I'd don't really know if it's possible and how...

I'd like to know your thougts on this.

EDIT

For example: is it possible to change the [`scrollTop`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/element.scrollTop) value **while** scrolling?

Cheers.

Comment: how so? what are you attempting to accomplish?

Comment: I think the OP is trying to change the scrolling speed as a function of the distance from the top of the page.

Comment: I think the OP is trying to change the scrolling speed as a nonlinear function of how fast he's moving the scroll wheel.

Comment: You probably either need a mouse driver or a browser extension. A web page can't override your device's behavior, nor the way a browser handles hardware scroll events.

Comment: I'll post this as a comment not an answer, since it's vague...I wrote a library to do this with touch, including a crude measurement of how fast the user was moving. Based on this, I adjusted the amount scrolled and the easing applied. So yes, it is probably feasible, and yes, you should be able to adjust scrollTop while scrolling.

Comment: @TimMedora: can you provide some links or maybe detail your approach in an answer? thx

Comment: @darksky there are many ways to accomplish this effect without needing anything like what you are describing.

Comment: @dqhendricks I'm very interested in learning them. The way I see it, the browser processes hardware events before notifying DOM. For instance, when the browser catches a scroll event coming from the mouse, it will process it by moving the page, and only then notifies DOM of the scroll event. That would mean even if you can catch scroll events, calculate the scroll speed, and so on, by the time you try to set the `scrollTop` the page has already moved.

Comment: @darksky perhaps take a look at my answer?

Comment: @dqhendricks I see your answer. You just want to move the top of an inner div. The main problem with your approach is, how do you get a scroll event for a non-scrolling object? When you give focus to a non-scrolling element, say your inner div, and scroll your mouse, your inner div won't get a scroll event, the page will. Because the page will just scroll.

Comment: @darksky In all of the browsers I have tested, when I have an inner element focused, scrolling bubbles up to the next element that scrolls (outer div). I don't see how my answer doesn't answer the original posters question, which involves a scrolling element. Whether the element that scrolls is the window or a div doesn't matter.

Comment: @dqhendricks I take back what I originally said. Tamlyn's answer below actually works!

Answer (score 2):

A high level approach to your problem:

1. Capture scroll events, keep track of the time you got the last one
2. Compute actual velocity *vA* based on time to last event

   ```
   vA(dT):
       // if we last scrolled a long time ago, pretend it was MinTime
       // MinTime is the dT which, when scrolled
       // at or less than, behaves linearly

       if (dT > MinTime) dT = MinTime
       vA = MinTime / dT
   ```
3. Devise some transformation to perform on *vA* to get desired velocity *vD*:

   ```
   vD(vA):
       // quadratic relationship
       vD = vA * vA
   ```
4. Calculate a "scroll factor" *fS*, the ratio of *vD* to *vA*:

   ```
   fS(vD, vA):
       // this step can be merged with the previous one
       fS = vD / vA
   ```
5. Calculate the delta scroll *dS* using *fS* and *dSi*, the initial scroll size (1 scroll event's worth of scrolling)

   ```
   dS(fS):
       dS = fS * dSi
   ```
6. Scroll by that much

   ```
   Scroll(dS)
   ```

If you scroll less than once per MinTime or slower, you will get typical linear behavior.  If you try to scroll faster, you will scroll quadratically with your actual scroll speed.

I have no idea how to actually do this with javascript, but I hope it provides somewhere to start.

Is there a unit of scrolling I can use by any chance?  My terminology looks funny.

Comment: Damnit now the word "scroll" looks really funny.

Comment: Thank you for that one! Not sure to understand all the variables refer to... Is `dT` the time between the 2 last scroll-events? Is `MinTime` a constant (If so, maybe you can express it caps-lock, eg: `MINTIME`)?

Comment: "Is there a unit of scrolling?" Humm well, `element.scrollTop` is in  `px`

Comment: dT is shorthand for delta time, and is, at the time of processing a scroll event, the time since the previous event was handled.  MINTIME or MinTime or whatever you want to call it is a constant with a value of your choice.  I'd go for maybe 1/2 second.

Comment: @abernier: I think I'll call it the blit.

Answer (score 1):

This should be helpful for capturing mouse wheel 'speed':

```
$(document).on('DOMMouseScroll mousewheel', wheel);


function wheel (event) {

  var delta = 0;

  if (event.originalEvent.wheelDelta) {
    delta = event.originalEvent.wheelDelta/120;
  } else if (event.originalEvent.detail) {
    delta = -event.originalEvent.detail/3;
  }

  if (delta) {
    handle(delta, event.currentTarget);
  }

  if (event.preventDefault) {
    event.preventDefault();
  }

  event.returnValue = false;
}

function handle (delta, target) {

   // scrollYourPageDynamiclyWithDelta(delta*delta);
   // manipulate of scrollTop here ;)

}
```

Answer (score 0):

So this is more conceptual, but I think using the functions that others mentioned to detect scroll speed and such this could be helpful.

Logic:

1. Disable defaults for scrolling on a div.
2. Add a second div that just detects mouse wheel speed using @Tamlyn's code. Perhaps you could put this div behind your working div or wrap it around or inside your content some how. I'd try to just put it on the side for now.
3. Next, scroll the div based on the input from this 2nd div. Use your custom scrolling function to change scroll speed based and direction of the scroll. There will be some "devil in the details moments" here probably.